# Using Nikto to better secure servers, and understanding output

Tags: apache-2.2, security

```
Im getting these output for the server I am testing against. 

- Nikto v2.1.4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Target IP:          
+ Target Hostname:    
+ Target Port:        80
+ Using Encoding:     
+ Start Time:        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Server: Apache
+ No CGI Directories found (use '-C all' to force check all possible dirs)
+ ETag header found on server, inode: 923575, size: 29, mtime: 0x4e4e14249db6a
+ Default account found for 'phpMyAdmin Setup' at /phpmyadmin/setup (ID '', PW '0000'). Deutsche Telekomm T-Sinus 130 DSL.
+ 6456 items checked: 0 error(s) and 2 item(s) reported on remote host
+ End Time:           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ 1 host(s) tested
```

A couple that concern me here are these two, how do I address these?

Server: Apache

ETag header found on server

I'm surprised by this being so open by default. Would probably never have noticed it.

Default account found for 'phpMyAdmin Setup' at /phpmyadmin/setup (ID '', PW '0000'). Deutsche Telekomm T-Sinus 130 DSL.

Answer (score 0):

**ETag** is a standard used for determining whether the client (web browser) already has the latest version of a document. If it has, it’s simply loaded from local cache. If not, the new version is requested. You can disable it by putting these two directives to the httpd.conf file:

```
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

Regarding phpMyAdmin, what authentication mode is configured? If you use **"config"** mode then I would recommend to switch to **"cookies"** mode as there is a risk that somebody can exploit it and read it from the configuration files. The mentioned auth modes are described [here.](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types)

Comment: I'm currently using config and will be switching it over to cookie, what perplexes me is that the phpMyAdmin Setup is in a router and unprotected.